# Combine list of Data Frames in one Data Frame

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

If I have list of Data Frames, for instatce:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [pagePath, date, visitors]
Index: []
pagePath      date  visitors
0  /themes/возврат-процентов-по-ипотеке/  20170504         4
1  /themes/возврат-процентов-по-ипотеке/  20170503         3
                            pagePath      date  visitors
0  /themes/возврат-процентов-по-ипотеке/  20170505         2
1  /themes/возврат-процентов-по-ипотеке/  20170506         2
```

and so on, how I can combine these Data Frames in one Data Frame with 3 columns? Also I need exclude empty Data Frames from final frames.

Comment: The result of pd.concat:

Comment: What's the point of concatenating an empty dataframe with another?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Unforchantly, this returns me separatly Data Frames like this:             pagePath      date  visitors
0  /question/1398635/  20170504       1.0
                                pagePath      date  visitors
0  /themes/возврат-процентов-по-ипотеке/  20170501         1
1  /themes/возврат-процентов-по-ипотеке/  20170502         1

Comment: OK, what is `for df in dfs: print (df.columns)` ? Maybe there is problem your columns are first row in data. How was created list of dfs?

Comment: Returns this: Index(['pagePath', 'date', 'visitors'], dtype='object')

Comment: Can you add output of `concat` to `question` ?

Comment: pagePath      date  visitors
0  /question/1398635/  20170504       1.0
                                pagePath      date  visitors
0  /themes/возврат-процентов-по-ипотеке/  20170501         1
1  /themes/возврат-процентов-по-ипотеке/  20170502         1
2  /themes/возврат-процентов-по-ипотеке/  20170504         4
3  /themes/возврат-процентов-по-ипотеке/  20170503         3
4  /themes/возврат-процентов-по-ипотеке/  20170505         2
                                      pagePath      date  visitors
0  /themes/документы-на-приватизацию-квартиры/  20170504       1.0

Comment: Can you add it to question? Because bad formating in comments.

Comment: It looks like different data frames

Comment: The result of pa.concat looks like exampel in my question

Comment: Ok, so in question are 2 dataframe and first is empty?